# What would happen if I disable the AMD Catalyst "launcher" from startup?

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon

Would it disable Radeon drivers? Would my Radeon options not be applied?

My PC is running Win 8.1

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather, the drivers would work, but I don't think the settings would be applied, unless there's a reason not to then I'd leave it enabled.